# MySQL don't select same id twice

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a message system, and i can't figure this out! The message system is built up something like this,

```
ID
MESSAGE_ID
MESSAGE
FROM_USER
TO_USER
```

The message_id can be the same multiple times, thats the ID the from and to users are reading from while checking messages (so they can see all the messages that has been written). But, i need to select all the messages, but i want to skip a row, if the ID has been select before. Is this possible in MySql? or do i need to run a array then remove all duplicated id's?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `ID`, `MESSAGE_ID`, `MESSAGE`, `FROM_USER`, `TO_USER`
FROM `YourDbTable`
GROUP BY `ID`, `MESSAGE_ID`
```

Group By may be what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Group by message_id** for that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this -

```
SELECT    DISTINCT (message_id), message, id, 
          from_user, to_user
FROM      test
GROUP BY  message_id
ORDER BY  id;
```

A live demo is given [here](http://ideone.com/cLfMW).

Comment: Thanks! Is there any easy way to only show the latest inserted IDs? I'm using codeigniter and trying something like this,

        $this->db->where('to_user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->order_by('message_id', 'DESC');
        $this->db->group_by('message_id');

Comment: @Ninja__1881: Sorry, haven't worked on CodeIgniter before but if you want the latest inserted IDs then I guess you can select rows in the descending order of the IDs, provided that the last inserted row gets the current highest ID plus 1 assigned to it.